# Change props of external component dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, gridsome

I'm new to VueJS and unfortunately I can't figure out how to change the `:leftImage` and `:rightImage` props of this external component [vue-compare-two-images-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-compare-two-images-component/v/1.0.4).
It's working then the props values are set to `null`. But if the props get a image src they not react to new value change.

My goal is to change the props value dynamically based on the button click.
Does someone knows how to achieve this?

```
<template>
    <ClientOnly>
        <img :src="imageBefore" > 
        <ul>
            <li><button class="button is-primary"  @click="Audi()">audi</button></li>
            <li><button class="button is-primary"  @click="Tesla()">tesla</button></li>
            <li><button class="button is-primary"  @click="Porsche()">porsche</button></li>
            <li><button class="button is-primary"  @click="reset()">resel all</button></li>
        </ul>
        <compare-two-images v-if="imageBefore"  
            :leftImage="imageBefore"
            :rightImage="imageAfter">
        </compare-two-images>
    </ClientOnly>
</template>
```

```
export default {
  name: 'Image Before-After',
  components: { CompareTwoImages },
  data () {  
    return {
          imageBefore: null,   // default null or some src
          imageAfter: null,
        }
  },
  methods: {
        reset(){
            this.imageBefore= null, this.imageAfter= null
      },
        Audi(){
            this.imageBefore =  '/assets/audi-before.jpg',
            this.imageAfter =  '/assets/audi-after.jpg'
        },
        Tesla(){
            this.imageBefore = '/assets/tesla-before.jpg',
            this.imageAfter = '/assets/tesla-after.jpg'
        },
        Porsche(){ 
            this.imageBefore = '/assets/porsche-before.jpg',
            this.imageAfter = '/assets/porsche-after.jpg'
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It should work. What's the issue? Are you able to see the images? Or its not changing images dynamically??

Comment: I can't change the images / props dynamically. It only works for <img :src="imageBefore" > but not for <compare-two-images>. The only thing that works is the reset button that set the prop values to null.

Comment: Then call reset function in each function before setting image paths. So in each button click first image will be null then it will be set to Audi or tesla or anything.

Comment: Also try adding :key="imageBefore" for reactivity

Comment: Hey @BeshambherChaukhwan thank you for your help. The :key prop solved my problem. Maybe someone knew a other way to code this efficient.

Comment: Then I think the reactivity was the issue. Do study more about it in here https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: you should remove the commas in your functions also you have to declare your properties in your Child component. Could you show use your CompareTwoImages.vue file?